# How to deal with double limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Let $l=\lim\limits_{x\nearrow 1}(1-x)^2f(x)-\lim\limits_{x\searrow1}f(x),$
>
> where $f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ and
> $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are defined as follows:
>
> $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1+2x+3x^2+\ldots+nx^{n-1},&x\leqslant1\\\\
> e^{n(1-x)},&x>1.\end{cases}$$
>
> Find $l.$

This is a problem in my workbook. I have never encountered double limits like this yet, and I have no clue how to deal with them. One thing I noticed is that, for $x\leqslant1,f_n(x)$ = $g'(x),$
where $$g(x)=x+x^2+\ldots +x^n = x\dfrac{x^{n-1}-1}{x-1}.$$
I suspect this must be used to find $l$. For $x>1$, I don't think there is anything special. Any hints on how to even begin this problem?

Comment: @Angelo All of the extra spaces (with `\;` and so on) make the text harder to read. It would be better without them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, for any $\,x<1\,,\,$ it results that

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nkx^{k-1}\right)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(x^k\right)=$

$=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}x^k\right)=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\dfrac x{1-x}\right)=\dfrac1{(1-x)^2}\;.$

Moreover, for any $\,x>1\,,\,$ it results that

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e^{n(1-x)}=0\;.$

Consequently ,

$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac1{(1-x)^2}\quad&\text{ for any }x<1\\\\\;0&\text{ for any }x>1\end{cases}$

Hence ,

$l=\lim\limits_{x\nearrow 1}\;(1-x)^2f(x)-\lim\limits_{x\searrow1}f(x)=$

$\;\;=\lim\limits_{x\nearrow 1}\;(1-x)^2\dfrac1{(1-x)^2}-\lim\limits_{x\searrow1}\,0=1-0=1\;.$